# Why the MS Charts is missing the horizontal x-axis line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, mschart

I am using asp.net charts i.e. MS Charts. It works but the problem is that the X-axis horizontal line is not coming.

aspx code:

```
    <asp:Chart ID="chartCMPM" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="950px">
     <legends>
          <asp:Legend Alignment="Center" Docking="Right" IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" LegendStyle="Column" />
     </legends>
      <Series>
         <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="PM" YValueMembers="SumPM" BorderWidth=1  PostBackValue="#VALX"> </asp:Series>

          </Series>
          <ChartAreas>
  <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
   </asp:Chart>
```

C sharp code:

```
    chart1.Series(0).ChartType = 
     DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column 
    chart1.Legends(0).Enabled = True chart1.Series("Series1").Label = 
    "#VALY"
    chart1.Series("Series1").LegendText = "Total"
    'chart1.Series("Series2").Label = "#VALY" '
    chart1.Series("Series2").LegendText = myYear.ToString 
    chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False 
    chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = False 
    chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1 
    chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 5 
    chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 0 
    chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LineWidth = 0
```

If I remove the line   `chartCMPM.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.LineWidth = 0` then then many horizontal line comes upto the height of chart but I want only one.

Now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsAdy.png)

but I want the line below it.

Comment: When I try to reproduce your issue in vb.NET I do not see the 'many horizontal lines', just the one on the X-axis. Would you please execute `chart1.Serializer.Save("chart.xml")` and show us the resulting XML?

Comment: Also, the lack of semicolons usually indicates vb.NET is being used, not C# with which you tagged the question. If so, would you please correct the tags?